# Persisting data with socket.io server on 'connect'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I'm using socket.io with MongoDB and promises. I'd like to save some data in Mongo when the session is established, and further socket events can't necessarily be handled properly until this data is saved.

```
// Simplified code
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) 
  var req = socket.handshake;

  mongoDbPromise.then(function (db) {
    return db.collection('mycollection').insert({some_user_data: req.query.some_user_data});
  }).then(function (insertResult) {
    // do some other work
  }).catch(function (error) {
    socket.disconnect();
    logger.info(error);
  });
}
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that the `connection` socket event is emitted immediately after this connection handler returns, but the work of setting up the connection continues when MongoDB's promise resolves and my `then` handler is called. Clients that make a request immediately after receiving `connection` see the app in an inconsistent state.

I can see two ways to resolve this:

1) Use a callback of some sort to control when `connection` is emitted. I haven't seen any sign in the socket.io docs that it's possible to do this, though.

2) Instead of using `connection` to signal that the socket is ready to go, use some other custom event (lets call it `connection_established`) and emit it in the `then` handler.

Is option 1 possible? Is there a better way of handling this case?

Comment: A few weeks ago, I implemented the method described in [this article](https://facundoolano.wordpress.com/2014/10/11/better-authentication-for-socket-io-no-query-strings/), and it's worked well for me.  Basically you allow clients to successfully connect,  but then have a second agreed upon handshake message AFTER authentication/data lookup is done.  Essentially your option 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you have async work to do in your connection handler (which you do), then you can't prevent the client from thinking it is connected before you are done with your work in the connect handler.  Your have a couple choices for solving that:

1. You can hook into the authentication process for the socket.io connection using middleware and use that feature to control things.  If your DB operation fails, you will essentially act like the connection is not authorized which will disconnect it.
2. You can send the client your own "connectionReady" message to the client and program the client end to not send you anything until it receives the "connectionReady" message which you will only send when the connection has finished doing it's thing (it sounds like you already have this idea with your thought of connection_established).

The auth process in socket.io v1 and higher can be done with middleware like this:

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
  var req = socket.handshake;

  mongoDbPromise.then(function (db) {
    return db.collection('mycollection').insert({some_user_data: req.query.some_user_data});
  }).then(function (insertResult) {
    // do some other work

    // socket is now ready to go
    next();
  }).catch(function (error) {
    // error on authentication
    next(new Error('not authorized');
    logger.info(error);
  });
});
```

The `connectionReady` process could work like this:

```
// Simplified code
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) 
  var req = socket.handshake;

  mongoDbPromise.then(function (db) {
    return db.collection('mycollection').insert({some_user_data: req.query.some_user_data});
  }).then(function (insertResult) {
    // do some other work

    // send client a message indicating that the connection is now ready
    socket.emit("connectionReady", true);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    socket.disconnect();
    logger.info(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: @Pathogen - did this answer your question?

Comment: Nearly! A detail I neglected to mention: I'm stuck with socket.io 0.9x for now. The `next` callback is exactly what I would have liked to use in the authorizer, but I'm stuck with the older style `io.set('authorization', ... )` API for authorization. Unless 0.9x can use middleware for authorization?

Comment: @Pathogen - Yeah, 0.9x is quite a bit different than 1.0+.  You will always have to mention that if you're asking for help as there is hardly any 0.9x development any more and even less documentation for it.  If this helped you figure it all out, then please indicate that to the community and click the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here on stack overflow for following the proper procedure.